# Install a docker - issue with sslstrip

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to follow a tutorial in order to install a docker:

`sudo yum -y update`

`sudo yum install -y docker`

But I got the following error:

```
Repository 'sslstrip': Error parsing config: Error parsing "baseurl = 'sslstrip'": URL must be http, ftp, file or https not ""
There are no enabled repos.
 Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
 You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

I tried couple of things but nothing has made me get rid of this issue.

How can I enabled sslstrip? How can I get rid of this issue about sslstrip?

Comment: Which distro are you using?

Comment: Linux version 4.13.0-45-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-011) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)) #50~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 30 11:18:27 UTC 2018

Comment: "I tried couple of things" - Please edit your question and indicate what you tried exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yum` is the installation manager for the RedHat family of distros (RHEL, Fedora, Centos). On Ubuntu you should use `apt`/`apt-get`:

```
sudo apt install docker-ce
```

However, since you seem to run a rather old Ubuntu version (16.04?), you have better install Docker from the Docker repository to get a recent version:

```
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
```

(the version in the Ubuntu repos is frozen at the time the distro version goes out, so installing with `apt` you would be running a 4- to 5-years old version).